# deblurring image by deconvolution using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, deconvolution

I have two images `o1` & `o2`, and I have blurred the two images using the same Gaussian blurring kernel. Then I have found kernel `k1 = DFT(b1) / DFT (o1)`,  where `b1` is the image obtained by blurring `o1`.

I have used this kernal (`k1`) to perform deconvolution on `b2`, where `b2` is obtained by blurring `o2`.

But deblurred output is not correct (the output image does not have any relation with original) what is the problem in my code ?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  Mat orig1 = imread(argv[1], 0);
  Mat orig2 = imread(argv[2], 0);

  Mat blur1, blur2;
  GaussianBlur(orig1, blur1, Size(11, 11), 0, 0 );
  GaussianBlur(orig2, blur2, Size(11, 11), 0, 0 );

  imshow("or1", orig1);
  imshow("bl1", blur1);
  imshow("or2", orig2);
  imshow("bl2", blur2);
  waitKey(0);



  deconvolution(orig1, blur1, orig2, blur2);

  return 0;
}
void deconvolution(Mat & o1, Mat & b1, Mat & o2, Mat & b2)
{
  Mat o1f, o2f, b1f, b2f;
  Mat o1dft, o2dft, b1dft, b2dft;

  o1.convertTo(o1f, CV_32F);
  b1.convertTo(b1f, CV_32F);
  o2.convertTo(o2f, CV_32F);
  b2.convertTo(b2f, CV_32F);

  computeDFT(o1f, o1dft);
  computeDFT(b1f, b1dft);
  computeDFT(o2f, o2dft);
  computeDFT(b2f, b2dft);

  Mat k1, k2, b1d, b2d;
  divide(b1dft, o1dft, k1);

  Mat r1, r2;
  divide(b1dft, k1, r1);
  divide(b2dft, k1, r2);

  Mat idftr1, idftr2;
  computeIDFT(r1, idftr1);
  computeIDFT(r2, idftr2);

  Mat r1_8u, r2_8u;
  idftr1.convertTo(r1_8u, CV_8U);
  idftr2.convertTo(r2_8u, CV_8U);

  imshow("r1", r1_8u);
  imshow("r2", r2_8u);
  waitKey(0);
  destroyAllWindows();
}
```

Images o1, o2, b1, b2, `r1` and `r2` are given in order below:

[image: o1 (original image - 1)]

[image: o2 (original image - 2)]

[image: b1 (original 1 blurred)]

[image: b2 (original 2 blurred)]

[image: b1 deblurred]

[image: b2 deblurred]

Comment: Can you be more explicit than "deblurred output is not correct" ? Real life is not CSI, deblurring is not an exact operation.

Comment: Because this is a visual question, I suggest adding a couple of pictures; both showing what you're getting currently and what you'd like to get.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely that your blurring kernel has vanishing coefficients for certain frequencies. For each coefficient of the transform of your signal (f) and blurring kernel  (h), you calculate f/h right now. This is effectively a division by zero for these coefficients, resulting in the strong noise you observe.

A quick solution for this would be pseudo-inverse filtering:

use f/h only for |h| > epsilon

set coefficient to 0 else

If this isn't smooth enough, you can get better results with 
[wiener filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution).