# Binarization of image in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm having a problem with binarization of image (perhaps blurry in general)
I have this image:

[image]

and after I've done binarization I get

[image]

How can I do better binarization? My goal is to have just black background and white letters and nothing else. I used adaptive threshold binarization

```
cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image_gs,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY ,41,3)
```

and I also have

```
kernel=np.ones(1,1)
```

Does anyone have idea how to do that?

Comment: try median filter before thresholding

Comment: and play around with parameters http://stackoverflow.com/a/31290735/5008845

Comment: @micka how to use median filter? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try deblurring methods, see these:

[Deblurring image by deconvolution using opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110861/deblurring-image-by-deconvolution-using-opencv)

[Experiments with deblurring using OpenCV](https://gigadom.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/experiments-with-deblurring-using-opencv/)

Answer (score 2):

Try out the following:

1.De-noise your image,first, by using either a Median,Bilateral,Gaussian or Adaptive Smooth Filter (Gaussian filter works pretty well when it comes to images with textual content).

2.De-blur the image by referring to http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/ or https://github.com/tvganesh/deconv

3.Check out Adaptive Gaussian thresholding,instead.In case its a scene text image,you can use Otsu's algorithm after shadow removal. 
The 'Image Processing in OpenCV' tutorials have a detailed documentation on Image Thresholding.

The Image Filtering — OpenCV 3.0.0-dev documentation explains the implementation of the Median Blur, applied to an image.